# Bash doesn't works for new user

Tags: bash, tty

I've just created a new user in my machine with *adduser --system --group studio* for audio purposes, and everything went ok until I've tried to open a terminal, which opened and closed immediately. 
I've tried using other terminals (xfce4-terminal, Xterm and UXterm) and the problem persisted.

Then I've tried logging in a tty, which showed a strange behavior: it logs in, shows that message *Last login: bla bla bla*, and quickly comes back to login screen. So I think the problem is with *bash* and this specific user. Logging on a tty with the older user still works.

I've also tried creating the files *.bashrc* and *.profile* (actually copying them from the working user), but it didn't fixed the problem either.

This is a very strange behavior for me, and I've never seen this before. As I can't access any shell from this user, I'm not able to diagnose the problem. I've checked *dmesg* and all logs possible and nothing shows up when the error happens. I'm using Debian Wheezy and XFCE4. My *uname -a* is:

```
Linux t4rkus-nb 3.2.0-4-rt-686-pae #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Debian 3.2.35-2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How very strange! What is the default terminal type for the user (can be found in /etc/passwd, last part of the string)? I would delete (as su) all .???rc files from the home directory so there's nothing "accidentally running"... If all else fails, delete the user and add again.

Comment: It was /bin/false, as a result of passing --system to adduser. Stupid is my middle name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you passing the `--system` flag? From the manpage:

> The new system user will have the shell /bin/false (unless overridden
>   with the --shell option), and have logins  disabled.  Skeletal
>   configuration files are not copied.

Meaning the new user has `/bin/false` as the shell, which immediately exists when you try to log in with it.

Comment: Oh, I certainly misunderstood the --system flag. Checking /etc/passwd clearly showed me the shell /bin/false for the user. I'll create it again without the flag. Thanks!

Comment: I had the right guess - "not a valid shell" - but you actually explained why. Kudos (and +1) to you.